# checkbox css/jquery style change

Tags: jquery, html, css, checkbox

The purpose of my codes is to change the *`<td>`* portion of the color and the font inside the table when I check/unchecked the box, but it didn't work as intended with the code I got from [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/c/checked/).

```css
input[type=checkbox] + td {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color:#000000
} 

input[type=checkbox]:checked + td {
    background-color: #00447C;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="details">
    <div class="container">
        <p>Example</p>
        <table id="table">
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Header 1</th>
            <th>Header 2</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td> <input type="checkbox"/></td>
            <td>element1</td>
            <td>detail1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td> <input type="checkbox"/></td>
            <td>element2</td>
            <td>detail2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td> <input type="checkbox"/></td>
            <td>element3</td>
            <td>detail3</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <button class="button">Reset</button>
    </div>  
</div>
```

It works in the source so I am confused regarding this.

Comment: when adding code to OP use `<>` to create a demo

Comment: sorry garuda, and thank you.

Comment: you want jquery solution or css only?

Comment: both, sorry. andd it seem like it requires both if I am not allowed to alter my html codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jquery you can do something like this:

```js
var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']");

function checkbox_function()
{
/*
  var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
  if ($(tr).hasClass('checked'))
  {
    $(tr).removeClass("checked");
  }
  else
  {
    $(tr).addClass("checked");
  }
*/
  var parent = $(this).parent();
  if ($(this).is(":checked"))
  {
    $(parent).siblings().addClass("checked");
  }
  else
  {
    $(parent).siblings().removeClass("checked");
  }
  
  
}

$.each(checkboxes, function(index, item) {
    $(item).change(checkbox_function);
  });
```

```css
tr.unchecked {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color:#000000
} 

tr.checked {
    background-color: #00447C;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}

td{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color:#000000  
}

td.checked{
    background-color: #00447C;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="details">
    <div class="container">
        <p>Example</p>
        <table id="table">
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Header 1</th>
            <th>Header 2</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td> <input type="checkbox"/></td>
            <td>element1</td>
            <td>detail1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td> <input type="checkbox"/></td>
            <td>element2</td>
            <td>detail2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td> <input type="checkbox"/></td>
            <td>element3</td>
            <td>detail3</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <button class="button">Reset</button>
    </div>  
</div>
```

What this does is get all the checkboxes and then puts a change listener onto them.

(Edit to your liking).

Comment: is it fine if i change the tr to td as it may conflict my header css codes

Comment: It is weird because the code is working i your snippet, but it doesnt work on mine, I will have to look at it again.

Comment: If you want it to only go with the td, I can change the code again. It was really just a lazy example. If you don't mind the tr, simply add a class to it so that it doesn't interfere with other tr stuff that doesn't have the class

Comment: I as told to not touch my html at all. so I just replaced all the tr as td in my jquery and css

Comment: I changed the answer so it only affects the tds (subsequent).

Comment: sorry a.Lau, I still can't seem to make the table and the fonts inside change colour when i checked the box.

When I check the debugger, there doesn't see m to be any error as well

Comment: Are you actually using jquery?

Comment: Yes, and maybe it could be jquery version not supporting the current codes? I am also not allowed to make any edits to my HTML, so I am unable to change my src jquery to the one in your script.

It is only linked to my .js and .css, and i can only make edits **only** to the both of them

<script src="myScript.js"></script>

Comment: can you do `console.log($("input[type='checkbox']"));` and see if it outputs anything?

Comment: do i just add that code in? or do i replace 'var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']");'

Comment: just add it below that. Also, you might need to check if your javascript is after or before your html

Comment: Ignore my comment above. Am isuppose to use it in <script>?

Comment: yes, it's just to check whether your jquery is working or not. You should be able to see it in your browser's console. Also, where is your javascript in comparison to your html? The javascript stuff should be after your html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135912/discussion-between-lala-and-a-lau).

Answer (score 1):

The `+` selector in CSS selects an element adjacent to the preceding selector. So `input + td` would select the `<td>` in the following example:

```
<input />
<td></td>
```

But not in this one:

```
<div>
    <input />
</div>
<td></td>
```

Thus, your CSS doesn't point to an existing `<td>` element in your markup.

**EDIT**: One (example) workaround to this would be to omit your `<td>` tags, since all standard-compliant browsers have implemented tables without `<td>`s.

Comment: then do i have to use + #table.td instead?

Comment: wait, but I've to use input because of my checkbox.

Comment: Sadly, you can't point to a parent/ancestor element with CSS. Your only option would be to change your markup, or to use JS. Pure CSS can't accomplish what you want with that exact HTML (to my knowledge).

Comment: that explans why they would let me finally touch my JS as well... thank you

Answer (score 0):

the plus sign in css means :

> Select and style every
>
> element that are placed immediately after  elements for div + p { background:'#fff'; }

That mean in your case it will select any td that comes right after input[..]

Answer (score 0):

The plus (+) refers to siblings, but your checkbox is a child of the cell, so you should use chevron (>) or space ( ) instead.

http://techbrij.com/css-selector-adjacent-child-sibling

However, you can't style the parent based on the child, only the other way round. So you might have to resort to javascript to add/remove a class from the cell.

Comment: The `>` selector points to a direct child of the preceding selector. Input elements cannot have child elements. **EDIT**: (referring to a previous revision of this answer)